# iptables is growing gradually on Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

We have an in house Kubernetes 1.15 cluster which is running on bare metal (Ubuntu 18.04) and consists of 7 workers and 1 master node. We have many namespaces and each namespace is hosting 25+ different components and some of these components need to be exposed to the outside via NodePort (having a reverse proxy for these components is not an option).

The problem is I noticed a gradual increase in the iptables size. Over a 2 weeks period around 400 lines were added to the iptables without we change the components running on the cluster and there is nothing else running on those machines. Since this happened before I am saving iptables and when I check I don't see any strange thing inside the iptables, it is just the normal rules required for the cluster. A big iptable can cause many problems including network packet drop and I am looking to find a solution for this.

I noticed this post on Kubernetes blog but that is just a tracking tool and not a tool that solve the issue: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/19/introducing-kube-iptables-tailer/

Answer (score 0):

What exactly bother you ?

- Is it the size of the iptables ?
- Do you have performance issue when scheduling a new service (meaning it takes *a lot* of time for your service to obtain an IP) ?

If it's just the size, then that is to be expected when you start to have undreds of pods/services. This is just how iptable works.

If it's a performance issue, then that means that you probably have thousands of components. If that's the case, Kubernetes 1.11 introduced IPVS to solve the issue.

Anyway, I invite you to have a look at those two articles :

1. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/
2. https://www.projectcalico.org/comparing-kube-proxy-modes-iptables-or-ipvs/

You should have a better understanding as to why you have a lot of entries in your iptable or why it is slow after reading them.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question we need to expose many services and ports as NodePort and k8s is writing 7 lines for each port in a NodePort service so it I know where they came from. The problem is without changing the configuration/adding new components the number of lines and therefore the size of iptables grows. A big iptable (beyond 10k lines) will cause many problems including packet loss and even kernel overflow. IPVS is also editing the iptables but to what extend I don't know. My main question is why the iptable size grows?

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that the table was growing without adding new component. Do you have some change on your cluster like cronjob scheduled (which can explain the apparition of new pods and therefore new entries in the table), HPA or just node maintainance which cause the pod to be re-scheduled (thus, new IP generated) ?

Comment: We don't have cronjobs and nodes are pretty stable and rarely need maintenance (our only problem so far was iptables) but we use HPAs extensively. I am considering to use cilium because of BPF, I heard that can solve the problems with iptables.